# java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: $Proxy205.dispatch(int, my.package.beans.AdapterHeader, my.package.beans.AdapterInfo)

Tags: java, spring, osgi

Has anyone been through this?

In the server side, in my OSGi application, I'm exporting a service. Here's the spring file code:

```
    <!-- RMI SERVICE EXPORT -->
<bean class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter">
    <property name="serviceName" value="IntegrationRemoteService" />
    <property name="service" ref="integrationExecutor" />
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="my.package.services.IntegrationService" />
    <property name="registryPort" value="$system{integration.port}" />
</bean>

<!-- INTEGRATION EXECUTOR -->
<bean id="integrationExecutor" class="my.package.engine.IntegrationServiceExecutor">
    <property name="integrationServiceImpl" ref="integrationEngine" />      
</bean>
```

My IntegrationServiceExecutor class extends the IntegrationService interface and implements the method:

```
public class IntegrationServiceExecutor implements IntegrationService {
...
@Override
public GenericResult dispatch(int serviceCode, AdapterHeader adapterHeader,    AdapterInfo  adapterInfo) {
```

The IntegrationService interface is defined in another component and this same component is used in my .war in the client side. In that component, I also have the implementation of the remote request called through my .war

```
...
import org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory;
import org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiProxyFactoryBean;
...

    public class GenericRmiFactory implements RemoteConnectionFactory {

private ProxyFactory proxyFactory;

public GenericRmiFactory(ServerTransport transport) throws ClassCastException, IllegalFormatException {
    RmiServerTransport rmiTransport = (RmiServerTransport) transport;

    RmiProxyFactoryBean rmiProxyFactoryBean = new RmiProxyFactoryBean();

    rmiProxyFactoryBean.setLookupStubOnStartup( false );
    rmiProxyFactoryBean.setCacheStub( false );
    rmiProxyFactoryBean.setRefreshStubOnConnectFailure( true );
    rmiProxyFactoryBean.setServiceUrl(String.format("rmi://%s:%s/%s", rmiTransport.getHostname(), rmiTransport.getPort(), rmiTransport.getServiceName() ));
    rmiProxyFactoryBean.setServiceInterface(rmiTransport.getRemoteInterface());
    rmiProxyFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();

    this.proxyFactory = new ProxyFactory(rmiTransport.getRemoteInterface(), rmiProxyFactoryBean);
}

private ProxyFactory getproxyFactory() {
    return proxyFactory;
}

@Override
public Object getRemoteService() {
    return getproxyFactory().getProxy();
}
}
```

I call the remote service in this way:

```
    ...
    IntegrationService integrationService = (IntegrationService) getGenericRemoteFactory().getRemoteService();
integrationService.dispatch(myInt, myAdapterHeader, myAdapterInfo);
...
```

This last statement throws the exception:

```
Invocation of method [public abstract my.package.result.GenericResult my.package.services.IntegrationService.dispatch(int,my.package.beans.AdapterHeader,my.package.beans.AdapterInfo)] failed in RMI service [rmi://127.0.0.1:2260/IntegrationRemoteService]; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: $Proxy205.dispatch(int, my.package.beans.AdapterHeader, my.package.beans.AdapterInfo)
```

Is there something I'm missing here?
Thanks in advance,
Karen

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this before.  You have to add 'throws RemoteException' to your interface method.  The client throws a NoSuchMethodException, but it's really complaining about the lack of RemoteException.